# PHPUnit dataProvider in CakePHP controller

Tags: phpunit

I am trying to write a Unit Test using dataProvider to test a controller method.

However the $this->contents always return null. Does dataProvider work in CakePHP's controller test case?

```
 public function initValidateDataProvider() {

    $data['Event']['event_type']    = 1;
    $data['Event']['event_id']      = 1;
    $data['Event']['year']          = date('Y');
    $data['Event']['name']          = 'test';
    $param[0] = $data;
    $provider[0] = $param;

    return $provider;
}

/**
 * @dataProvider initValidateDataProvider
 *
 */
public function testInitValidationAll($data) {

     $this->testAction(
        '/sb_organizers/events/init',array(
            'return' => 'contents',
            'data'   => $data,
            'method' => 'POST'
        )
    );

    debug($this->contents);
}
```

debug($this->contents); always return null.

But if I run it without dataProvider:

```
    public function testInitValidateAll() {
    $data['Event']['event_type']    = '';
    $data['Event']['etag_id']       = 0;
    $data['Event']['year']          = '';
    $data['Event']['name']          = '';

    $this->testAction(
        '/sb_organizers/events/init',array(
            'return' => 'contents',
            'data'=>$data
        )
    );
    debug($this->contents);
    }
```

It works fine. Does dataProvider work in CakePHP's controller test case? I suspect it is the $this->testAction does not work with dataProvider.

Comment: Did you check that the $data array is the same in both cases by doing a var_dump()?

Comment: @gontrollez yes. they are the same. If the data format is different, PHPUnit will throw exception. If the data content is different,$this->contents will still return something.